# How to enable all Woo Commerce shop features if disabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please assist with enabling all woo commerce features (add to cart, checkout, etc) to the website http://maxedev.beetleinc.co.za ... It seems the previous developer disabled all Woo Commerce features but I cant figure out how exactly. There is no plugin used to disable these features so I am assuming this is code based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inspected the source and it looks like its either using a 'catalog mode' plugin or code has been added to your functions.php folder in the theme's folder. If you post it up here I can inspect it for you. also a list of your activated plugins would help.

Comment: Hi, I eventually solved this issue with some deep research. Turns out there was a code conflict in the functions.php file that was causing Woo Commerce shortcodes to not function properly. The add to cart button is now visible and users will be able to add to cart and access the checkout page. Thanks !

Comment: No worries, glad you got sorted!